# Mixing less and scss/sass or how to include Angular material definitions in less files?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, less, angular15

I'm using `less` for the definition of my component's style in Angular 15.

Now, with Angular Material's theme definition I've a `theme.scss` that works fine.

But how can I define thing's that work fine in the scss area like

```
@include mat.button-density(-3);
```

in `less`?

Or do I have to switch my whole project from `less` to `scss?` Is less in someway outdated and not state of the art anymore?